# HTTP GET Response parse error (empty String?) - but body is not empty

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, http

I am working on a Javascript snippet that communicates with a **local** Java Server with the help of HTTP Requests.

My requests looks like this:

```
var req = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "http://127.0.0.1:8081", 
    data : data_dict
});
```

The response header, that I send from my Java Server, seems to be okay (at least the Firefox Web Developer tells me so). But there is an error on body parsing:

> JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the json data

Seems like my response is empty... but when I open
http://127.0.0.1:8081/?test_request_key=test_request_value it shows the expected body in my browser:

> {"test_respond_key":"test_respond_val"}

Do you have a hint for me? I have no idea where to search for the problem...

**EDIT:** The complete Response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Java HTTPStudyServer
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 39
Connection: close

{"test_respond_key":"test_respond_val"}
```

Thanks in advance!
(and sorry if this is a noob problem with a simple answer, but some hours of googling didn't help me out)

Comment: In your dev tools, what is the type of content being returned (text/plain, application/json, etc)? Also try checking for any hidden characters and try pasting your response into, and running it through, [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It tells me that my json string is correct. I added the complete response to the main post. Seems not like there is an empty sign in it :(

Comment: How are you *processing* the response?

Comment: Tried this by defining success and error just below data and by defining req.done and req.fail functions. It always ends up in the error/fail function.

Comment: On which URL is your page located? It looks like CORS may comes into play.

Comment: The HTML file is here <project_root>/HTML/intro.html and
the JAVA files are here <project_root>/JAVA/... . I thought this counts as same-origin, since both are running on the same machine?

Comment: Does maybe the port lead to the treatment as "not from the same origin"?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution (with your help!)

The problem was indeed CORS! If you look at the examples at http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy you see that **for another port it does not count as same origin**!

This post gave me proof: [Why is same origin policy kicking in when making request from localhost to localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262775/why-is-same-origin-policy-kicking-in-when-making-request-from-localhost-to-local)

So I simply **added this line to the Response Header**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Now it works like a charm! :)

Thank you for your help guys!

Greetings

Comment: Per MDN's same origin policy page, "Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is specified), and host are the same for both pages." So, that a port is being specified induces this. I suppose one could run all localhost traffic through an nginx (or other reverse proxy) instance, mapping your separate port's JSON response through an /api endpoint, making the CORS header issue moot.